# wordpress get current user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a directory inside my wordpress directory for some template application

```
apacheWWW/wordpress/jtpc
```

In my application i want the wordpress current user id

I am able to do this in one page but in the other I get an error

This is what I am doing to get the user id:

```
require_once( '/../../wp-load.php' );
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

but I get an error on this line

```
 require_once( '/../../wp-load.php' );
```

The error says

```
 File does not exist: D:/programming/apacheWWW/wordpress/jtpc/ajaxHandlers/wp-admin, referrer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23
```

what dose he wants with the wp-admin , 
and why he is looking for it in the wrong directory ,
It's suppose to be under

```
   D:/programming/apacheWWW/wordpress/
```

It's working for one page, (I am uploading file and creating a directory for this user id)

but for the other page I send an ajax request to delete files by user request 
so I need to id again, but there he throws the error

Answer (score 3):

ok got i working i put

```
  require_once( '/../../wp-load.php' );
```

at the top of the page
and not inside the function

Answer (score 2):

My issue is that I've set up a standalone ajax controller for my plugin's admin.
In hindsight, I wish I didn't, because now I need $current_user->ID on a particular method.

using the following code gives me undefined function errors:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

same when I use this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

I've used GREP to trace the spaghetti function calls, and was able to get stable using the following chain of includes within my ajax_request method of my base controller:

```
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'meta.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'plugin.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'user.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'capabilities.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'load.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'functions.php';
include APP_ROOT.'wp-includes'.DS.'pluggable.php';
```

(I have defined my own APP_ROOT, which is the include path to the base of the whole application.)

This eliminates my errors, but I am still getting a user id of 0, and data is NULL, which doesn't solve my problem.

Surely there is a better way to do this. Has anyone deciphered the cookie or session variables for direct access?

Any and all suggestions would be welcome. I know I'm asking a lot for wordpress to work like normal OOP/MVC code...

In addition, I have deployed a CodeIgniter front-end, and I am using WordPress solely for the back-end. I highly recommend this for ultimate flexibility if you are forced to use WordPress. Front-end hooks are a pain, and really kind of "hacky". Here's where I got the idea:

http://jidd.jimisaacs.com/post/wordigniter-wordpress-codeigniter/

So if anyone has any questions about that, I bet I could help.

Best regards, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try one of the following two lines:

```
require_once STYLESHEETPATH . '/wp-load.php';
```

or

```
require_once TEMPLATEPATH . '/wp-load.php';
```

There is a slight difference between the STYLESHEETPATH constant and the TEMPLATEPATH constant. If you are developing a child theme, STYLESHEETPATH will be the child theme path, while TEMPLATEPATH will be the parent theme path.

Comment: i am getting error for this 

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant STYLESHEETPATH - assumed 'STYLESHEETPATH' in D:\\programming\\apacheWWW\\wordpress\\jtpc\\ajaxHandlers\\addon_handler.php on line 22, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23

AND                   

[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant TEMPLATEPATH - assumed 'TEMPLATEPATH' in D:\\programming\\apacheWWW\\wordpress\\jtpc\\ajaxHandlers\\addon_handler.php on line 22, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23

Comment: Something wrong with your settings. You may want to install XAMPP on your PC and try WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get current user:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

After that, you can use `$current_user->ID` where you want.

**More Info:**

- [Function Reference/wp get current user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Comment: also error here 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in D:\\programming\\apacheWWW\\wordpress\\jtpc\\ajaxHandlers\\addon_handler.php on line 24, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23