# Wordpress get current user data from new php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a new php page and I'm using wordpress for my website.

From within my new php file I've included wp_load..

```
include ('wp-load.php');
```

which I believe is required in order to retrieve current user details.

I've then tried to echo the current loginname:

```
$current_user->user_login
```

but it's coming out empty and I know it's not..

UPDATE:

This is what I'm trying...

```
include ('wp-load.php');
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$myuserlogin = $current_user->user_login;

echo $myuserlogin;
```

This is not returning anything...

I'm I missing anything?

RESULT:

This is the var_dump result:

[object Object]1object(WP_User)#79 (10) {
  ["data"]=>
  NULL
  ["ID"]=>
  int(0)
  ["id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["caps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["cap_key"]=>
  NULL
  ["roles"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["allcaps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["filter"]=>
  NULL
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380177/wordpress-get-current-user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
  include ('wp-load.php');
  global $current_user;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  var_dump($current_user);
?>
```

Comment: The vardump is returning NULL and empty strings so the include is not getting the current user details for some reason or I'm missing something?

Comment: If you not logged in its returning empty strings. Otherwise they filled. Ive cehck it on my WP 3.2.1

Comment: Was your file in the theme root or server root?

Comment: server root. try to replace include with require